# Looking for way to have REST web service accessed through ESB

Tags: architecture, rest, soap, esb

I am preparing on how to present using an ESB, such as Glassfish, to a company I am working with, but I realized that they may want to have some of their new webservices switch from SOAP to REST, and this is where I run into a problem, as my experience with ESBs (mainly BEA's ALSB) is that they seemed to be geared toward SOAP.

I would prefer to have some central place for webservice clients to connect to, as the final server that will process it will change, over time, as new applications are bought.

So, is there an open-source ESB that can handle REST and SOAP webservices?

Comment: James, maybe there is an opportunity window to switch to REST as the primary integration strategy. Then you could do away with the ESB altogether and switch to Squid or TrafficServer as a substitute?

Comment: Unfortunately they have many webservices, and I am implementing a learning management system, so many webservices will need to be repointed, and my suggestion is to use an ESB so that they don't have to keep paying a cost to redo the clients. They haven't used REST at all yet, so I will be suggesting that, but it may not mesh with their culture.

Comment: Have you tried Mule, or Ws2O, or Apache Synapse or serviceMix?

Comment: @Jimmy zhang - Will these work with REST web services, if I am returning images, JSON or comma-delimited files?

Comment: I am pretty sure they will at least work on POX and SOAP